# WebHook update for Google Fit Activity

Tags: webhooks, google-fit

I would like to get user Google Fit activity updates to my server (via webhook) so there is no need to make request periodically.

Currently i have a cron job to get data, but has two problems, infrastructure complexity and delay from the data generation and data processing.

I have seen that there is a Google Report Api but does not support Google Fit.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push

Comment: Any update on this post, I have the similar needs

Comment: same here, any update?

Comment: Anyone from Google Fit looking into it? Fitbit and Garmin API support callbacks long time back.